# Темизация таксономии Drupal 6

Tags: drupal

Как переопределить стандартный шаблон вывода таксономии в Drupal 6 (везде натыкаюсь только на howto для 7 версии).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

также добавлю , что шаблон  node-taxonomy.tpl.php по умолчанию не определен - его надо определить в файле  template.php  вашей темы

```
function ИМЯТЕМЫ_preprocess_node(&$vars) {
  if(arg(0) == 'taxonomy'){
    $suggestions = array('node-taxonomy');
    $vars['template_files'] = array_merge($vars['template_files'], $suggestions);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

чтобы темизировать материалы выводимые на странице терминов используйте шаблон node-taxonomy.tpl.php
чтобы темизировать страницы терминов используйте page-taxonomy-term.tpl.php